# System.ExecutionEngineException upon attaching to exe process

Tags: c#, .net, com, dllimport, visual-studio-debugging

A custom .NET application integrates COM dlls and their functions. This application works like a charm **on every machine** (Windows Server 2012 and Windows 10) until...

- ... I try to attach to an execution process, then it **immediately** throws a `System.ExecutionEngineException`, which does not have any additional information / inner exception / call stack or anything.
- I execute it on specific machines. More Strange: Server A and Server B have both Windows Server, with the same .NET and other components on them - nevertheless if I **attach** my Visual Studio 2015 to **Server A** via the Remote Debugger Service, the application hangs up and I receive the `ExecutionEngineException` immediately and regardless of the currently executed method, so even if none of the `DllImported` methods are executed at the moment. **But** if I **attach** to **Server B**, then I can debug the very same application without crashing and receiving exceptions.

How is it possible, that I have different outcomings with the same application freshly copied to different Windows machines? Do some registry entries or any other configuration influences how Visual Studio attaches to processes.

Remark: I develop plugins as third-party to this application, so I do not have sources and PDBs. My biggest problem is, that I went out of troubleshooting steps (comparing installed programs/features/roles on each machine, checking .NET version, make a fresh copy of the application files to have identically same executions)

I appreciate every help and assumptions!

> System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.

Comment: `ExecutionEngineException` is special type of exception, which crashes the process immediately, you can check event log for details only. It can be caused by some assertions in your or .NET code, or some issues in the marshaller. Try to check the event log and check the call stack, maybe it gives you some ideas

Comment: Thanks Pavel for your reply! Unfortunately, the call stack is empty. I might have looked at on the wrong Event logs, that's why I haven't found any useful entries, but I'll double-check it.

Comment: Hi Perry, thanks for the link! Ian provides some detailed description in that thread about the nature of this kind of exception, but the questioner haven't make any efforts to analyze the source of the problem.

I'll continue my troubleshooting tomorrow or on Wednesday, and try to update you. I might stumble upon something interesting worth sharing...

Comment: In the Event Viewer under the node Windows I haven't found any entries from the beginning of the application till crash. Am I searching in the wrong place? Are there any debug tools to get a better trace about crash?